# tf.exe authenticate for vsts

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to list all the workspaces and trying to authenticate tf.exe with vsts using the below commandline.

tf workspaces /Collection: https://[account].visualstudio.com/defaultcollection /login:USername,Password

The vsts account is backed by Azure Active Directory synced with an on-prem AD.

It works fine when I have connected to the vsts from visual studio and then running the above tf.exe command without the login switch.

But, when I use the login switch for tf.exe and use the same credentials that I use in visual studio it throws

TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://[account].visualstudio.com/defaultcollection
TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://[account].visualstudio.com/defaultcollection

What I am trying to achieve is that I am going to provision a server and then not going to login to visual studio and want my tf to work as it works when logged in to the visual studio online account in the team explorer of my visual studio.

I am an admin of the vsts account and have full right on everything. If there are other ways of doing this possibly authenticate TF.exe using PAT token that would work as well.

I would use tf.exe again for a checkin command from automated builds.
Any help in solving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the Check in changes task in [TFVC Build Tasks extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-tfvc-tasks) that you can use it to check in changes. Also, you can call TF command to check in changes during the build process, it uses build service account.

On the other hand, you can create a console application to check in changes through TFS API ([Workspace.CheckIn method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff732574(v=vs.120).aspx)), then call this app through command line.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue (`TF30063`) when running `tf.exe`.  For me the solution was:

- Exit all running instances of Visual Studio
- Rename `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache` to `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache_old` (or you could delete it; but I wanted to preserve the original so I had the option restore it when going back into VS).  NB: the `7.0` varies according to which version of TF you're using.
- Navigate to my project's folder `pushd c:\projects\vsts_tfvc_repos\Project123`
- Run `tf /collection:myinstance.visualstudio.com /workspace:%computername% 
  /login:myMicrosoftAccount@example.com,myPassword` to initialise the session under the correct account
  Thereafter, everything worked as expected...

Comment: Okay. Will try and tell you

Comment: I can't get this to work against dev.azure.com. I haven't been able to find how to use tf.exe to connect to Azure DevOps

Comment: @OliverNilsen you're best off asking a new question, and stating what you've tried / what errors you're seeing.  Mention you tried the solutions on this post and that they didn't work.  Then people can help you to resolve your specific issue.

Comment: @OliverNilsen I'm having trouble doing this on Azure DevOps. Have you figured this out?

Comment: @NerdinTraining: FYI this answer was based on Azure DevOps (back when it was called Visual Studio Team Services; but same product, just rebranded).  If this solution doesn't work for you, you're best off posting a new question, and listing this answer as something you've already tried.

Comment: @OliverNilsen I did. See here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963611/set-branch-policies-from-azure-devops-pipeline-with-tf-exe