# List Checked-Out Files from Azure DevOps / TFVC

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to get a list of files checked out from my TFVC repository hosted on Azure DevOps. I am the administrator of the repository. I have a local workspace, and all file changes take place through Visual Studio (2017), which does a formal check-out of each file as I change it.

My plan was to use the "tf status" command to connect to and query the repository, but I can't get past authentication issues. I first tried this command.

```
tf status /Collection:https://example.visualstudio.com/MyProject /login:me@example.com,MyPassword
```

It responded with the error:

```
TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: https://example.visualstudio.com/MyProject.
Team Foundation Server Url: https://example.visualstudio.com/MyProject.

Possible reasons for failure include:
- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
- The Team Foundation Server is offline.
- The password has expired or is incorrect.

Technical information (for administrator):
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

I tried to access the default collection:

```
tf status /Collection:https://example.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection /login:me@example.com,MyPassword
```

This time, the error is different.

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://example.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.
TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://example.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.
```

If I leave off the trailing collection name:

```
tf status /Collection:https://example.visualstudio.com /login:me@example.com,MyPassword
```

It returns a related error.

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access example.visualstudio.com\example.
TF30063: You are not authorized to access example.visualstudio.com\example.
```

I found a similar question at [tf.exe authenticate for vsts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106863/tf-exe-authenticate-for-vsts), but in that question, the OP was using an on-site TFS instance. My repository is only stored in VSTS / Azure DevOps.

How can I get a list of checked out files, that is, of files modified but not yet checked in from my local workspace?

Comment: How are you specifying your login and password?  Your AAD or MSA account will not work.  Have you created a personal access token or alternate credentials?

Comment: I tried a personal access token, including one with full access rights, but the response was the same in each case.