# Set branch permissions from Azure DevOps Pipeline with tf.exe

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Powershell script that tries to set branch permissions that is getting called in a Build Pipeline. Unfortunately, I am getting an unauthorized error and I'm not sure why.

Code Snippet:

```
$tfExe = "$(split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)\tf.exe"
& $tfExe git permission /deny:CreateBranch /group:[$project]\Contributors /collection:https://dev.azure.com/$organization/ /teamproject:$project /repository:$reposiName /login:$username,$pat
& $tfExe git permission /allow:CreateBranch /group:[$project]\Contributors /collection:https://dev.azure.com/$organization/ /teamproject:$project /repository:$reposiName /branch:feature /login:$username,$pat
```

Error Message:

> TF30063: You are not authorized to access
>   https://dev.azure.com/Company-DevOps. TF30063: You are not authorized
>   to access https://dev.azure.com/Company-DevOps. TF30063: You are not
>   authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/Company-DevOps.

Powershell Script in Build Pipeline:

[image: Powershell Script in Build Pipeline]

Any thoughts?

Comment: `tf` is sort of being deprecated slowly in favor of `az devops`: See the last section of this blog post: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/

Comment: @Nerd in Training Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I found my answer yesterday :S I will post an answer shortly

Comment: @Nerd in Training Could you share your answer here? This could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I have posted my answer below with all the steps!

Comment: @jessehouwing you are a life saver by the way. I saved your blog post on my Sharepoint site so I never forget!

Comment: @NerdinTraining You are not working with branch policies here. You are working with security groups. Please be sure to use the correct terminology for things; *branch policies* are a different feature.

Comment: @DanielMann Ya I confused the 2. Let me see if I can edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I wasn't able to get this to work with tf.exe as Microsoft Docs advised us to, but I was able to figure it out with the help of a blog [here](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/).

### Step 1

Get the `$descriptor` value for the Contributors group

```
$descriptor = az devops security group list --org https://dev.azure.com/$organization --project $project | ConvertFrom-Json | select -expand graphGroups | where principalName -eq "[$project]\Contributors"
```

### Step 2

Create your token values for the branches you want. Unfortunately, you cannot explicitly state which branch pattern you would like. Azure DevOps requires the Hex value (don't ask)

```
#Create the tokens
function hexify($string) {
    return ($string | Format-Hex -Encoding Unicode | Select-Object -Expand Bytes | ForEach-Object { '{0:x2}' -f $_ }) -join ''
}

$hexFeatureBranch = hexify -string  "feature"
$featureToken = "refs/heads/$hexFeatureBranch"

$hexSprintBranch = hexify -string  "sprint"
$sprintToken = "refs/heads/$hexSprintBranch"

$hexHotfixBranch = hexify -string  "hotfix"
$hotfixToken = "refs/heads/$hexHotfixBranch"
```

### Step 3

Get the Namespace ID for your Git Repos

```
#Get the namespace ID for the organization's Git repos
$namespaceId = az devops security permission namespace list --org "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/" --query "[?@.name == 'Git Repositories'].namespaceId | [0]"
```

### Step 4

Get the project's JSON object from the server

```
#Get the Project's JSON object
$projectObj = az devops project show --org https://dev.azure.com/$organization --project $project | ConvertFrom-Json
$projectid = $projectObj.id
```

### Step 5

Put a **Deny** on `CreateBranch` for every branch in your repo. The Azure CLI requires you to know which bits for allow and deny need to be. Luckily, I was able to do this by capturing the JSON response when I did it via the UI.

```
$denyBranch = az devops security permission update --id $namespaceId --org https://dev.azure.com/$organization --subject $descriptor.descriptor --token "repoV2/" --deny-bit 16 --allow-bit 16494
```

### Step 6

Put an **Allow** on CreateBranch for every branch that has the pattern feature/*, sprint/* and hotfix/*

```
$featureTokenBuild = "repoV2/$projectid/$repoid/$featureToken"
$sprintTokenBuild = "repoV2/$projectid/$repoid/$sprintToken"
$hotfixTokenBuild = "repoV2/$projectid/$repoid/$hotfixToken"

$allowCreateBranchFeature = az devops security permission update --id $namespaceId --org https://dev.azure.com/$organization --subject $descriptor.descriptor --token $featureTokenBuild --deny-bit 0 --allow-bit 16
$allowCreateBranchSprint = az devops security permission update --id $namespaceId --org https://dev.azure.com/$organization --subject $descriptor.descriptor --token $sprintTokenBuild --deny-bit 0 --allow-bit 16
$allowCreateBranchHotfix = az devops security permission update --id $namespaceId --org https://dev.azure.com/$organization --subject $descriptor.descriptor --token $hotfixTokenBuild --deny-bit 0 --allow-bit 16
```

It wasn't easy but at least for anyone in the future looking to do the same, here is the solution!

Comment: Good stuff! Would you like to turn this into a guest post on my blog?

Comment: @jessehouwing This is basically your work massaged to fit my problem. You can do as you please! You basically saved my butt at work :)

Comment: I'm surprised the branch prefix works as a wildcard. That's VERY useful!

Answer (score 2):

The username & password in the `/login` is for Azure DevOps Server. for Azure DevOps you should use `OAuth`:

```
param ($oauth)
/loginType:OAuth /login:.,$auth
```

In the agent job options you need to enable the "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token":

[image]

And pass the `$(System.AccessToken)` as `oauth` parameter:

[image]

Comment: version 14 of tf.exe doesn't support OAuth as a logintype

Comment: what is version 14? I tried above with tf.exe that come with VS 2019 and it works

Comment: Very helpful! In a powershell script it'd look something like this: & tf.exe /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN /noprompt