# TF.exe git permission login failing in pipeline yet correctly logs in locally

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfvc

I am trying to automate a process using TF.exe within an Azure DevOps pipeline. I am trying to run:

```
.\TF.exe git permission /collection:MyOrganization /login:MyPersonalAccessToken /noprompt
```

which correctly signs me in locally. However, when I run that same command in a PowerShell script that's running in an Azure Pipeline, it fails with

```
TF30063: You are not authorized to access MyOrganization
```

I've tried this without the PAT as well, instead using direct login credentials. Still, local login works completely fine, but in pipeline it will not go through with the same error.

I cannot use System.AccessToken at the moment, because we are first testing the automated workflow against a different organization (I am administrator in both). Is using TF.exe via pipeline only supported when logging in with OAuth Token?

Comment: Are you using a self hosted agent?
You are unable to use System.AccessToken because your using the pipelines of organization A for the git peremission of organization B?

Comment: Yes - I know System.Access won't work across org - so I've been using a PAT generated for all orgs just to see it work. However, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

Without the right organizational Oauth the only thing left seems to use the Azure Command-Line Interface (CLI).

Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59196862/8843952), IMHO the same issue.